# Getting input for file copy in Python

Tags: windows, python-2.7

I am trying to make a simple Python tool for copying all the contents from drive x to drive y, where it asks the user what the source and destination drives are. 
Works great when I run it from inside Visual Studio, but when I try to run it via the command line (`python.exe pythonapplication1.py`), I get this error in the output:

```
What is your source drive letter?f

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pythonapplication1.py", line 7, in <module>
inputSrc = input("What is your source drive letter?")
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'f' is not defined
```

Here is my code for this program:

```
import os
import sys

inputSrc ="x"
inputDest = "y"

inputSrc = input("What is your source drive 
letter?")
inputDest = input("What is the destination drive 
letter?")

src = inputSrc + ": "
dest = inputDest + ": "

copyCommand = "xcopy " + src + dest + "/s"

os.system(copyCommand)

loopCheck = "no"

while loopCheck == "no":
questionTest = input("Want to make another copy? y/n ")
if questionTest == "y":

    input("Press any key once you put in the new blank drive.")
    os.system(copyCommand)
if questionTest == "n":
   loopCheck = "yes"
```

Comment: I thought it might have been because I wasn't initializing any variable before filling it with user input, so that's why I have the x/y stuff at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `raw_input("question...")` instead of `input("question...")` in python2. This is because `input` will take the users input and execute it. This is why the interpreter complains about not knowing `f`.

Comment: Nothing on OP's "Works great when I run it from inside Visual Studio"?

Comment: Might be that he used python3 in VS. Or that VS injects a variable `f` into the global scope or so (I hope not). It's hard to tell without having Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`

i.e.

```
inputSrc = raw_input("What is your source drive 
letter?")

inputDest = raw_input("What is the destination drive 
letter?")
```

will work.